# Differentiation of a function

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a non-constant, thrice  differentiable function such that $f(1+1/n)=1$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$.  then what is the value of $f^{\prime \prime}(1)$? [image]

Answer is 0

Comment: What do you mean with for all $x$? For $x=0$ this is not well-defined.

Comment: pretty sure he means $x\in \mathbb Z^+$

Comment: Let $c\in\Bbb R\setminus\{1\}$. Then putting $x=1/(c-1)$, we have $f(c)=1$. Hence, $f$ is constant after extending by continuity.

Comment: Since the second derivative of $f$ at $1$ is assumed to exists [then we can write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative#The_second_symmetric_derivative) $$f''(1) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1+h) + f(1-h) - 2f(1)}{h^2} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(1+1/n) + f(1-1/n) - 2f(1)}{1/n^2} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1 + 1 - 2\cdot 1}{1/n^2} = 0$$

Comment: @Winther: please post your answer as an answer, and not as a comment.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose we have a two times continuously differentiable function $g$ such that $g''(1)>0$, then we can find an interval $[1,1+\delta)$ such that $g''(x)>0$ for all $x$ in the interval.

The function $g$ cannot take on any given value more than $3$ times in this interval, why?

It is a consequence of the mean value thoerem, suppose that $a_0<a_1<a_2$ and $g(a_j)=z$ for all values.

Then by Rolle's theorem there are two points $a_0<b_1<a_1<b_2<a_2$ with $g'(b_0)=g'(b_1)=0$. A contradiction, since $g''$ is positive in $[1,1+\delta)$, which implies $g'$ is increasing in the same interval.

The case when $g''(1)<0$ is analogous.

Can you see why this result solves your problem? It is because no matter what $\delta$ you obtain you get an infinite number of values in $[1,1+\delta)$ that map to $1$. So we must have $g''(1)=0$.

Answer (score 6):

Since $f$ is continuous at $x=1$ we have $f(1) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(1+1/n) = 1$. We can now use [the symmetric formulation for the second derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative#The_second_symmetric_derivative) to get

$$f''(1) = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(1+h)+f(1-h)-2f(1)}{h^2} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(1+1/n) + f(1-1/n) - 2f(1)}{1/n^2} = 0$$
since $f(1+1/n) + f(1-1/n) - 2f(1) = 1 + 1 - 2 \equiv 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: we have  $f (t)=1$ for  all  $t \ne 1$.

Comment: the problem with this interpretation to the problem is that you just need continuity.

Comment: Thinking about it I don't think this is true at all. I think it's possible to construct an infinitely many times differentiable function that is only equal to $1$ along the sequence $1+1/n$ - and nowhere else - by defining something like $f(t) = 1 + \frac{1}{n^3}e^{-\frac{1}{(t - 1-1/n)^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{(t - 1-1/(n+1))^2)}}$ on the intervals $[1+1/(n+1), 1+1/n]$.

Comment: Why on earth does this answer have 5 upvotes? As Winther mentioned, the function needs not be constant on any interval. For instance, you could have $$ f(t)=1+(t-1)^7\sin\left(\frac\pi{t-1}\right),$$ this function is three times differentiable (if extended by $f(1)=1$), $f(1+\frac1n)=1$ for all $n$, and it is never constant.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I've realized what the problem is - this answer was correct before one of the edits in the question, since then the question has stated "$f(1+1/x)=1$ for all $x$". I guess the correct course of action would be now for Fred to delete this answer.

Comment: We don't have any idea what $f(1.56) is.

Comment: @Wojowu: good catch. Bad situation then, hard to avoid the problem when a (reasonable) edit changes the question completely.

Comment: Instead of deleting this, one possible way forward is to just edit it with something ala "The original question was written as "if $f\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right) = 1$ for all $x$ what is $f''(1)$" and the answer above was an answer to that question. When the question was changed by resticting $x$ to be an integer then this is no longer true as the counter-example Martin Argerami provided $f(t) = 1 + (t-1)^7\sin(\pi/(t-1))$ shows." Just having an answer which shows that $f$ does not have to be the constant function is quite interesting imo and I'm sure it will be useful for many users here.